Osm2po routing custom response
I have an osm2po service running on http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService/ when specifying two points and asking for the route between them this request is sent
http://localhost:8888/Osm2poService/?cmd=fr&ui=osm2po&source=45.46574,11.6296&target=45.48511,11.62253&findShortestPath=false&ignoreRestrictions=false&ignoreOneWays=false&routerId=0&heuristicFactor=0.0&maxCost=0.0&hull=false&tsp=&route and i get this list of coordinates 45.4659685,11.6293319,45.466099,11.6291713,45.4661922,11.629093,45.4661922,11.629093,45.4662512,11.6290538,45.4663426,11.6290492,45.4664373,11.6290616,45.4664808,11.6291325,45.4664808,11.6291325,45.4667837,11.6288887,45.4671675,11.6285178,45.4671675,11.6285178,45.4673414,11.628323,45.4678188,11.6277889,45.4678188,11.6277889,45.4678834,11.6277211,45.4678834,11.6277211,... . Is there a way to make the response return the ids of the traversed segments. Thanks in advance
